# Error while integrating with google sign in

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to integrate with google calendar to sync the events that I am creating on our portal with google calendar

I am stuck on the very first step

I have created client from the google API console and fetched the client_id successfully

Now when I am adding the code for the js script

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="4xxxxxxxxx-900m5xxxxxxxxxxdu69jrlhdasasasab.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-callback="handleClientLoad">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

I am getting this error

> [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.
> [image]

I have added mutliple origin for testing this on my local server as well as a https server but its not working

Please help!